# Armstrong Calculation function crashes

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function in c++ that calculates all armstrong numbers up to an upper-limit sent as an argument to the function.  For some reason, my function doesn't identify 153 as an armstrong number and it crashes after identifying 9474.  Here is what I have so far:

```
void isArmstrong(int curr_value, int arm) {

    //tmp value to hold original upper limit
    int curr_value1 = curr_value;

    //accumulator to keep track of how many armstrong numbers have been found
    int armstrong = 0;

    //determining how many digits long the current tested number is for armstrong testing
    string currStr = to_string(curr_value);

    //the power the current tested number will be raised to
    int nth = currStr.length();

    //cout <<"num " << armStr<<endl<<"nth "<<nth << endl;

    //variable to break out of loop
    int accum = 0;

    //sum variable to check if the number is armstrong after computational testing
    int sum = 0;

    //temp number to add to the variable 'sum'
    int tmp = 0;

    //cout <<"-----"<< curr_value << endl;

    while (accum <= nth) {
        //calculating a numbers sum by raising each digit to the nth power and adding that to sum
        int digit = curr_value1 % 10;
        curr_value1 = (curr_value1 / 10);

        tmp = pow(digit, nth);

        sum += tmp;

        accum += 1;

    }

    //if sum and the current value are the same, the number is an armstrong number
    if (sum == curr_value) {
        armstrong += 1;
        cout << sum << endl;
    }

    //making sure the current value is less than the upper limit and calling the function again
    if (curr_value < arm) {
        isArmstrong(curr_value += 1, arm);
    }

}
```

Here is how I'm calling the function from main:

```
isArmstrong(1, 54748);
```

and here is the console output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no debug message.  The console hangs and then it says armstrong.exe has stopped working.

Comment: I have modified my answer with my suggestion. You can check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead making too many recursive call which has a chance of making your stack full, do this.**

`for(int i=1;i<=54748;i++) if(check_armstrong(i)){//..do your work };`

Simply my suggestion is making iterative calls rather than doing too many recursive calls.

Too many recursive calls makes your program halts as stack gets full with the frames of called functions. That's why instead of depending on deep recursion you should use the iterative version which is independent of stack memory.

Simply each time a function is called you need to store some data regarding that function in memory. So only a certain number of calls can fit in memory. Here when you made the function call 9474 times, memory becomes full. That's why it halts.

Extra points:

1. The condition needs to be checked. `while(accum<nth)`.
2. You were storing the number of armstrong numbers in a local variable. If you want to use it, you can use either global variable( Not recommended) or you can simply keep it outside the the function and use it seperately from the function itself.

Functions are supposed to be modular, performing only one action. In my suggested solution you can see, you can reuse the `check-armstrong` function several times which is ideally the essence of using functions.

### Hint:

```
bool check_armstrong(int curr_value) {

    //tmp value to hold original upper limit
    int curr_value1 = curr_value;


    //determining how many digits long the current tested number is for armstrong testing
    string currStr = to_string(curr_value);

    //the power the current tested number will be raised to
    int nth = currStr.length();

    //variable to break out of loop
    int accum = 0;

    //sum variable to check if the number is armstrong after computational testing
    int sum = 0;

    //temp number to add to the variable 'sum'
    int tmp = 0;


    while (accum < nth) {
        //calculating a numbers sum by raising each digit to the nth power and adding that to sum
        int digit = curr_value1 % 10;
        curr_value1 = (curr_value1 / 10);

        tmp = pow(digit, nth);

        sum += tmp;

        accum += 1;

    }

    //if sum and the current value are the same, the number is an armstrong number
    if (sum == curr_value) {
        return true
    }
    return false;

}
```

In the loop you can do this

```
for( int i =1;i<=... )
{
   if( check_armstrong(i))
   {
      cout<<i<<endl;
      armstrong_count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.